# VSCode Php debugger is not working on when using WSL2

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, wsl-2, php-8

I've installed WSL2 on Windows 10, setup LAMP and install php-xdebug.

On `/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini` I've added this:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

after that I run the `sudo service apache2 restart` command.

Then added break point in VSCode, visited the local development site on Chrome and it doesn't work. It doesn't stop on the break point.

I've been doing this previously on WSL for more than 2 years now, but now I can't figure out why it doesn't work anymore...

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What's your PHP and Xdebug versions?

Comment: xdebug 3beta....

Comment: 1) Xdebug 3.0 has been released already 2) the config options that you are using -- they are for Xdebug v2. 3 out of 4 options do NOTHING in v3 that uses DIFFERENT options now. Check the upgrade guide and properly configure Xdebug v3: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: it seems its not working for php-debug extenstion in vscode.. that extention also is oudated for php8

Comment: I do not see how a VSCode extension will have any impact here. Unless we are talking about CLI debug (where extension passes additional Xdebug specific parameters to PHP itself).